# AWS CloudFront redirect to path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution that redirects www.myapp.com to my S3 bucket where my website is stored.
The distribution uses CName www.myapp.com and Default Root Object "index.html".

I want to also redirect www.myapp.com/path to the same bucket so users can either get to my website through www.myapp.com and www.myapp.com/path.

Anyone has any idea how to use CloudFront to redirect a custom path to bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using a behavior for /path/ and a lambda function on origin request:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = {
        status: '301',
        statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: "https://" + event.Records[0].cf.request.headers.host[0].value.replace(".s3.amazonaws.com", ""),
            }],
        },
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's not a redirect, it's origin behavior
2. You can setup different Origin Path for Origin and Path Pattern for Behavior. Behavior is target and Origin is destination

Comment: Ok so my bucket has a folder called mywebsite and a file called index.html, I have a single origin with my bucket name and path /mywebsite. Which behavior/default root object do I need to apply to I have access my web site through www.website.com/path

Comment: /path as  Path Pattern for Behavior, /mywebsite as Origin Path for Origin, and index.html as  Default Root Object of Distribution

Comment: I think Default Root Object of Distribution only works on the root of your distribution, so it will only go to index.html for www.website.com and not for www.website.com/path

Comment: Oh, you are right. Just found that AWS response for that: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-default-root-object-subdirectory/