# accessing path through cloudfront gives access denied

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I got a website hosted in cloudfront using an origin id to acess angualr app data in my non-public s3 bucket.
things work fine except that users cannot access paths like [www.exmaple.com/path](http://www.exmaple.com/path), users do get access denied. They always have to start at root.
I need to enable that access but am struggeling. I found that post, but frank, I dont understand it.
[AWS CloudFront redirect to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60609319/aws-cloudfront-redirect-to-path)

I found a workaround by making bucket public and use static website hosting, problem is only that users can bybass cloudfront and go to bucket right away.

anybody got a hint on how to enable paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some post explaining it.

1. U need to use the static website hosting enpoint an make it public
2. In cloudfront you set a header named Referer and give some random secret as value.
3. You put a bucket policy like this:

   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
   "Effect": "Allow",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": [
   "s3:GetObject",
   "s3:GetObjectVersion"
   ],
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yours3bucket/*",
   "Condition": {
   "StringLike": {
   "aws:Referer": "yoursecretvalue"
   }
   }
   },
   {
   "Effect": "Deny",
   "Principal": "*",
   "Action": [
   "s3:GetObject",
   "s3:GetObjectVersion"
   ],
   "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::yours3bucket/*",
   "Condition": {
   "StringNotLike": {
   "aws:Referer": "yoursecretvalue"
   }
   }
   }
   ]
   }